# Get independent parameters from Solve for solving diophantine equation

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I need to solve some diophantine equations, in some cases, results returned by `Solve` the included parameters are not all independent. For example, the flowing case I want $c_{14}$ as a separate parameter, since the range of each parameter is deterministic, otherwise, subsequent processing is inconvenient. Are there any suitable options or workarounds?

```
mat = Partition[Array[c, 25], 5];
equations = {Equal @@ Join[Total[mat], Total[mat, {2}], 
  {Tr[mat], Tr[Reverse[mat]]}], Total[mat, 2] == Total[Range[25]]};
sol = Solve[equations, Flatten[mat], Integers][[1]] // Normal;
TextGrid[mat /. sol, Frame -> All]
```

[image]
The result I hope is like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do an algebraic replacement for that position.

Start as above:

```
mat = Partition[Array[c, 25], 5];
equations = {Equal @@ 
    Join[Total[mat], Total[mat, {2}], {Tr[mat], Tr[Reverse[mat]]}], 
   Total[mat, 2] == Total[Range[25]]};
sol = Solve[equations, Flatten[mat], Integers][[1]];

mat2 = mat /. sol /. ConditionalExpression[a_, __] :> a

(* Out[21]= {{C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4], 
  65 - C[1] - C[2] - C[3] - C[4]}, {C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8], 
  65 - C[5] - C[6] - C[7] - C[8]}, {C[9], C[10], C[11], C[12], 
  65 - C[9] - C[10] - C[11] - C[12]}, {C[13], -65 + 2 C[1] + C[2] + 
   C[3] + C[4] + C[5] - C[8] + C[9] - C[11] + C[13], 
  1 + C[7] + C[10] + C[11] + C[12] + 2 C[14], 
  162 - 2 C[1] - C[2] - C[3] - C[4] - C[5] - C[6] - C[7] - C[9] - 
   C[10] - C[11] - C[12] - C[13] - C[14], -33 + C[6] + C[8] + C[11] - 
   C[13] - C[14]}, {65 - C[1] - C[5] - C[9] - C[13], 
  130 - 2 C[1] - 2 C[2] - C[3] - C[4] - C[5] - C[6] + C[8] - C[9] - 
   C[10] + C[11] - C[13], 
  64 - C[3] - 2 C[7] - C[10] - 2 C[11] - C[12] - 2 C[14], -97 + 
   2 C[1] + C[2] + C[3] + C[5] + C[6] + C[7] - C[8] + C[9] + C[10] + 
   C[11] + C[13] + C[14], -97 + C[1] + C[2] + C[3] + C[4] + C[5] + 
   C[7] + C[9] + C[10] + C[12] + C[13] + C[14]}} *)
```

Now use `PolynomialReduce` to do the desired replacement.

```
mat3 = PolynomialReduce[mat2, newC[14] - mat2[[4, 4]], C[14]][[All, All, 2]]

TextGrid[mat3, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify which of the variables that you want excluded, *Mathematica* will use which ever ones fall out of the algorithms naturally. To preclude solving for `c[14]` use `Drop[Flatten[mat], {14}]` for the variable list.

```
mat = Partition[Array[c, 25], 5];

equations = {Equal @@ 
    Join[Total[mat], Total[mat, {2}], {Tr[mat], Tr[Reverse[mat]]}], 
   Total[mat, 2] == Total[Range[25]]};

sol = Solve[equations, Drop[Flatten[mat], {14}], Integers][[1]] // Normal;

TextGrid[mat /. sol, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Similarly, if you want to exclude `c[5]` and `c[14]`

```
sol2 = Solve[equations, Delete[Flatten@mat, {{5}, {14}}], Integers][[1]] // 
   Normal;

TextGrid[mat /. sol2, Frame -> All]
```

[image]